# Approve PayPal Order but serverside

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, paypal

I have this code for payement:

```
  generatePayPalButton() {
    paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: async () => {
          const res = await this.sendReq.postReq("/api/paypal/create-order", { quantity: 1 })
          return res.id
        },
        onApprove: function (data: any, actions: any) {
          const capture = actions?.order?.capture().then((details: any) => {
            console.log(details)
          })
        },
        onCancel: () => {
          console.log("Canceled")
        },
        onError: (e: any) => {
          console.error(e)
        }
      })
      .render("#paypal")
  }
```

You can clearly see, that Im approving the order in the frontend.
But I want to approve the order in the backend and save it to a database.

Here is my backend code:

```
router.post("/api/paypal/create-order", async(req, res) => {
    const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest()
    const quantity = req.body.quantity
    const total = quantity * dataController.payement.pricePerNight
    request.prefer("return=representation")
    request.requestBody({
        intent: "CAPTURE",
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                currency_code: "USD",
                value: total,
                breakdown: {
                    item_total: {
                        currency_code: "USD",
                        value: total,
                    },
                },
            },
        }, ],
    })

    try {
        const order = await paypalClient.execute(request)
        res.send({ id: order.result.id })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Paypal error: `, e.message)
        res.send(e)
    }
})
```

So in the backend I just have a route, where Im giving the order id back, so I can charge the user. But how can I be sure that he paid. Can I check a token or something in the backend?

Im using:
NodeJs, express
@paypal/checkout-server-sdk
Angular
sendRequestService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approval step *always* takes place on the client side. The person paying is giving their approval, and they don't live inside your server, they connect to it via a client.

However, the steps immediately prior to approval (create order) and after approval (capture order, which is what actually creates a transaction) are both done from a server.  You'll need a server route for each of these; looks like you already have a create route.  The second capture route should take an `id` as input, capture it, do any validation such as checking that any successful transaction was for the correct amount before returning a response to the client. (Error/unsuccessful transaction responses should also be propagated back to the client, so it can display an appropriate message or restart in the case of INSTRUMENT_DECLINED)

For approval on the client, use this flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server